# ASP.NET MVC 5 Server code cannot call Javascript client SignalR function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, nservicebus, signalr-hub

In our application I want to have a "realtime" grid of notifications that the user can monitor. That grid is a **KendoUI grid** with SignalR-transport and is read-only. So the only hub method defined is a **Read** method.

This is my hub that is hooked up to the KendoUI grid.:

```
[HubName( "NotificationsHub" )]
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    public IApplicationSupportService Service { get; set; } //injeccted with Autofac

    public NotificationsHub()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<EventViewModel> Read()
    {
        var events = from e in Service.FindEvents()
                     select new EventViewModel
                     {
                         EventId = e.EventId,
                         Text = e.Text,
                         CreatedOn = e.CreatedOn
                     };
        return events;
    }
}
```

I also have a NServiceBus message handler that is supposed to call a client side method called "addEventToPage". The notification handler receives a nevent from the service bus and is supposed to call all clients to update their grid.

**This is the message handler on the server side, that uses a singleton helper to call the hub's clients via context.Clients.All.addEventToPage():**

```
//NServiceBus message handler subscribes to an event, then calls clients
public class NotificationsHandler : IHandleMessages<IBusinessEventReceived>
{
    public void Handle( INewEventWasSaved message )
    {
        NotifyTicker.Instance.UpdateClient( message.EventId, message.Text );
    }
}

public class NotifyTicker
{
    // Singleton instance
    private static readonly Lazy<NotifyTicker> _instance = new Lazy<NotifyTicker>(
        () => new NotifyTicker( GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>() ) );

    private IHubContext _context;

    private NotifyTicker( IHubContext context )
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public static NotifyTicker Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }

    public void UpdateClient( int eventId, string text )
    {
        _context.Clients.All.addNewEventToPage( eventId, text );
    }
}
```

**The client code:**

```
<script>
    var hubProxy;
    var hubStart;

    $(function () {

        var connection = $.connection;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        hubProxy = connection.NotificationsHub;

        //this function is called by message handler on server
        hubProxy.client.addNewEventToPage = function (eventId, text) {

            console.log(eventId + ' ' + text);
        };

        hubStart = $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () { console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
            .fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });


        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            editable: false,
            columns: [
                { field: "Text" }
            ],
            dataSource: {
                type: "signalr",
                autoSync: true,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "EventId",
                        fields: {
                            "EventId": { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            "Text": { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                transport: {
                    signalr: {
                        promise: hubStart,
                        hub: hubProxy,
                        server: {
                            read: "read"
                        },
                        client: {
                            read: "read"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see I am adding the "`addEventToPage`" method BEFORE the hub proxy starts. But the method is not called, period.

Originally, that method was supposed to add a `EventViewModel` to the KendoUI grid's datasource like so:

```
        dataSource.add({
            EventId: eventId,
            Text: text
        });
```

But that didn't work. It can't even write to the console.

**The connection is established successfully, with web sockets. I can confirm that in the Chrome console output.**

What am I missing?

**Is there maybe a better way to update the grid without a customer client -side function? Maybe I can tell teh grid to Re-Read?**

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. Is the NServiceBus handlers executed?

Comment: @RamonSmits yes the NSB handlers execute, they call the client method like I showed above, but nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SignalR. I did however made the two work together with NServiceBus v5.x https://github.com/ramonsmits/SignalR.NServiceBus/commits/nsb-v5

Comment: I updated most nuget packages in that solution to the latest versions to make sure that it would still work.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @RamonSmits not yet the weekend was in the way. Question: is this backplane the only way to make a call to SignalR from a message handler? Why would my solution not work? Thanks again.

Comment: No, the backplane is only needed if you have a webfarm but it is not required to use the NServiceBus implementation. I don't know much about SignalR. Do you have a project to reproduce it?